# Adding an OR constraint in JuMP/Gurobi

Tags: julia, gurobi, julia-jump

I'm trying to add a constraint to a model that constrains a variable to be one of the values in a set, i.e. constrains X to be 0 OR 3 OR 4.

Current code is as follows:

```julia
@addConstraint(m, x==4)
```

But I would like to do something like:

```julia
@addConstraint(m, x==0 or x==3 or x==4)
```

Is this possible in julia? Using JuMP as the solver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define helper variables `h3`, `h4` to be binary and then set constraints: `x = 3*h3 + 4*h4` and `h3 + h4 <= 1`.